# How to remove blue border around option elements in select box AND blue option color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As question title says, I am wondering how to remove that default blue border around option box when clicked on select?

And, how to remove default blue that shows on hover over that same option?

**UPDATE** I noted many of You understood me wrong, acctually [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMXZR.png) is what I want to customize.

Comment: I think you want to set `outline: 0` based on your description. Note though that `select` and `option` elements are very restricted in their styling and this may not work in all browsers. If you want to customise your select lists in a consistent manner, use a plugin instead.

Comment: set outline:0 in your css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 elements:

```
select{
    border: none;
    appearance: none;
    color: red;
}

select option{
    color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/8y47anso/3/)**

Note: Currently there is no way to apply css(hover) in the option to get your desired result

Comment: Hello @luis-p-a Can You please check my EDITED question. Also if plugin is only solution, do You know some very good one that is not slow and heavy? Thanks and sorry for asking many things.

Answer (score 2):

with CSS

```
input, select{
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery Plugin which may help you.

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)